# am not able to mapping the auto complete textbox value in mvc

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-ajax

Actually when i debugging my code it is hitting the json action but searching value is passing like \"\a\" this,what is the problem am not getting, anybody help me

this is my view:

```
@model IEnumerable<autoCompelte.Models.Student>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#search").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Home/AutoComplte",
                    data: {term :JSON.stringify( request.term)},
                    type: "POST",
                    datatype:"json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            return {
                                label: item.Description,
                                value: item.Id
                            }
                        }))
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                        alert('Failed to retrieve states.');
                    }      
                })
            }
        })
    })
</script>
....
<p><input type="text" id="search" name="search"></p>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>   
    @foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)</td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Id }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Id })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

This is my controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(db.Students.ToList());
}

public JsonResult AutoComplte( string term)
{
    var result = from n in db.Students
                 where n.Name.ToLower().StartsWith(term.ToLower())
                 select n.Name;
    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: `data: {term :request.term },`

Comment: i removed the JSON.stringify then string value is passing in correct format,but that value not binding to texbox

Comment: All your returning is an array of strings - there are no properties `Description` and `Id` so `label: item.Description,` etc do not work (but not sure what your want)?

Comment: when type the letter in textbox  that letter matching name should bind  to textbox below like dropdown,then how to bind it to text box sir?@stephen

Comment: Try just `label: item, value: item` (but as I noted, I'm not really sure what you want to display)

Comment: In fact if your just returning a collection of names, then all it need to be is `response(data);`

Comment: i want to display names which are match with text box letter @@stephen sir

Comment: Then just use `response(data);` as per my previous comment.

Comment: i got it sir@stephen thank you for help

Comment: when will we use item.property name,and how we will get the property names..

Comment: Sorry, not sure I understand your last comment. If your referring to your previous usage of `label: item.Description, value: item.Id` then that would only be applicable if your were returning a collection of objects with properties `Id` and `Description`

Comment: ok thank you @stephen sir